# How can I convert the "arguments" object to an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arguments, variadic-functions

The `arguments` object in JavaScript is an odd wart—it acts just like an array in most situations, but it's not *actually* an array object. Since it's [really something else entirely](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments), it doesn't have the useful functions from [`Array.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype) like `forEach`, `sort`, `filter`, and `map`.

It's trivially easy to construct a new array from an arguments object with a simple for loop. For example, this function sorts its arguments:

```
function sortArgs() {
    var args = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
        args[i] = arguments[i];
    return args.sort();
}
```

However, this is a rather pitiful thing to have to do simply to get access to the extremely useful JavaScript array functions. Is there a built-in way to do it using the standard library?

Comment: closely related: [how does Array.prototype.slice.call() work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7056925/1048572)

Comment: I don't like that all the answers to this question have perceived some intention to do a sort, and `sort` has permeated all the answers, but sorting was just _one example_ of something you _could do_ with a proper array.  The intent was to get the array.  I can't even blame the question because it properly says "for example".  Yet every answer has decided to roll in "sort" into the example for converting the arguments to an array -- sometimes too tightly conflating sorting with getting an array of arguments.

Answer (score 766, accepted):

### ES6 using rest parameters

If you are able to use ES6 you can use:

**[Rest Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)**

```js
function sortArgs(...args) {
  return args.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
}

document.body.innerHTML = sortArgs(12, 4, 6, 8).toString();
```

As you can read in the [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters)

> The rest parameter syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

If you are curious about the `...` syntax, it is called *Spread Operator* and you can read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

### ES6 using Array.from()

Using **[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)**:

```js
function sortArgs() {
  return Array.from(arguments).sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
}

document.body.innerHTML = sortArgs(12, 4, 6, 8).toString();
```

`Array.from` simply convert Array-like or Iterable objects into Array instances.

---

---

### ES5

You can actually just use `Array`'s [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) function on an arguments object, and it will convert it into a standard JavaScript array. You'll just have to reference it manually through Array's prototype:

```
function sortArgs() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return args.sort();
}
```

Why does this work? Well, here's an excerpt from the [ECMAScript 5 documentation itself](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.10):

> **NOTE**: The `slice` function is intentionally generic; it does not require that its **this** value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method. Whether the `slice` function can be applied successfully to a host object is implementation-dependent.

Therefore, `slice` works on anything that has a `length` property, which `arguments` conveniently does.

---

If `Array.prototype.slice` is too much of a mouthful for you, you can abbreviate it slightly by using array literals:

```
var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
```

However, I tend to feel that the former version is more explicit, so I'd prefer it instead. Abusing the array literal notation feels hacky and looks strange.

Comment: In recent Firefox versions (2.0?) and ECMAScript 5, there's an Array.slice method that make this a little simpler. You would call it like this: var arge = Array.slice(arguments, 0);.

Comment: converting array-like objects to arrays via `slice()` unfortunately deson't work reliably across browsers - eg IE can't convert node lists this way; for a general function which works with all array-like objects, there's no way around manually looping over the entries

Comment: What's the `0` for? Since there are no arguments you want to pass, why can't you just use `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` ? [ **The MDC arguments page** ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/functions_and_function_scope/arguments) suggests the method without the `0`.

Comment: @Christoph - IE should be able to convert `arguments`. This is because `arguments` has a properly set `length` property. As long as this is the case, the above method should work. (This works in IE 8: http://jsfiddle.net/6fyUT/ )

Comment: Why is the `sort` necessary? It's the one part that isn't self-explanatory (provided one understands the methods). In what circumstances would the one liner `return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);` not produce the same results?

Comment: @Barney - the sort is necessary because the original question wants to sort the arguments. If you just want to convert it to an array, it's not necessary.

Comment: In short this can be: `[].slice.call(arguments)`

Comment: For anybody that wants to know, you can easily append and prepend items into the `arguments` variable simply by using splice. E.G. `Array.prototype.splice.call(arguments,0,0,'new element');` (this will modify the arguments object without converting it to an array)

Comment: "You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in JavaScript engines (V8 for example)." - from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

Comment: I'm not sure that is answering to the original question. Time went by. With ES6 experimented in Firefox and Chrome, the _rest parameter_ is becoming a good alternative - `function sortArgs(...argsToSort) { return argsToSort.sort(); }` from MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Comment: The shortened way to do it has been beyond helpful for me.

Comment: I don't see many real-world cases where not slicing arguments to improve perceived performance.

Comment: @frameworkninja What about `Array.from()` ? Does that also prevent optimizations ?

Comment: [Array.prototype.slice](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp) is ES1 which means that it works in all browsers. The only caveat is that it doesn't work on host objects in IE 8 and older. But since the arguments object is not a host object, that does not apply here. (If you need your code to work on host objects on old IE, use an Array.from polyfill.)

Answer (score 40):

It's also worth referencing [this Bluebird promises library wiki page](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers#3-managing-arguments) that shows how to manage the `arguments` object into array in a way that makes the function optimizable **under V8 JavaScript engine**:

```
function doesntLeakArguments() {
    var args = new Array(arguments.length);
    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; ++i) {
        args[i] = arguments[i];
    }
    return args;
}
```

This method is used in favor of `var args = [].slice.call(arguments);`. The author also shows how a build step can help reduce the verbosity.

Comment: +1 and thanks for the link to the Bluebird Optimization Killer page. PS: I've recently seen this optimization used in the [node-thunkify](https://github.com/tj/node-thunkify/commit/d537460eb23e3d556c4f726eb04bef189dd3994f) project.

Comment: For anyone reading in 2021, on the linked page: "Please do not take anything written here as performance advice, this is here for historical reasons."

Answer (score 30):

```
function sortArgs(){ return [].slice.call(arguments).sort() }

// Returns the arguments object itself
function sortArgs(){ return [].sort.call(arguments) }
```

Some array methods are intentionally made not to require the target object to be an actual array. They only require the target to have a property named **length** and indices (which must be zero or larger integers).

```
[].sort.call({0:1, 1:0, length:2}) // => ({0:0, 1:1, length:2})
```

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
function sortArguments() {
  return arguments.length === 1 ? [arguments[0]] :
                 Array.apply(null, arguments).sort();
}
```

`Array(arg1, arg2, ...)` returns `[arg1, arg2, ...]`

`Array(str1)` returns `[str1]`

`Array(num1)` returns an array that has `num1` elements

You must check number of arguments!

`Array.slice` version (slower):

```
function sortArguments() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).sort();
}
```

`Array.push` version (slower, faster than slice):

```
function sortArguments() {
  var args = [];
  Array.prototype.push.apply(args, arguments);
  return args.sort();
}
```

Move version (slower, but small size is faster):

```
function sortArguments() {
  var args = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i)
    args[i] = arguments[i];
  return args.sort();
}
```

`Array.concat` version (slowest):

```
function sortArguments() {
  return Array.prototype.concat.apply([], arguments).sort();
}
```

Comment: Note that because of the flattening behavior in Array.concat, it will accept array arguments. sortArguments(2,[3,0],1) returns 0,1,2,3.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using jQuery, the following is a good deal easier to remember in my opinion:

```
function sortArgs(){
  return $.makeArray(arguments).sort();
}
```

Comment: That's essentially what I was looking for in pure JS, but +1 for the solid example of how jQuery makes JS a bit easier to grok.

Comment: "Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."

Answer (score 9):

In ECMAScript 6 there's no need to use ugly hacks like `Array.prototype.slice()`. You can instead use [**spread syntax (`...`)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
(function() {
  console.log([...arguments]);
}(1, 2, 3))
```

It may look strange, but it's fairly simple. It just extracts `arguments`' elements and put them back into the array. If you still don't understand, see this examples:

```js
console.log([1, ...[2, 3], 4]);
console.log([...[1, 2, 3]]);
console.log([...[...[...[1]]]]);
```

Note that it doesn't work in some older browsers like IE 11, so if you want to support these browsers, you should use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 5):

[Here is benchmark](http://jsperf.com/ghel-args) of several methods converting arguments into array.

As for me, the best solution for small amount of arguments is:

```
function sortArgs (){
  var q = [];
  for (var k = 0, l = arguments.length; k < l; k++){
    q[k] = arguments[k];
  }
  return q.sort();
}
```

For other cases:

```
function sortArgs (){ return Array.apply(null, arguments).sort(); }
```

Comment: +1 for benchmarks.  Currently the graphs show your `sortArgs` is 6 times faster in Firefox, but twice as slow in the latest Chrome, compared to `Array.apply`.

Comment: Since Array.prototype.slice is deprecated because it prevent JS V8 engine optimization I consider this the best solution until ES6 will be widely available +1

Comment: Moreover Array generics methods like Array.slice() are also deprecated

Answer (score 5):

Here's a clean and concise solution:

```js
function argsToArray() {
  return Object.values(arguments);
}

// example usage
console.log(
  argsToArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
  .map(arg => arg*11)
);
```

[`Object.values( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) will return the values of an object as an array, and since `arguments` is an object, it will essentially convert `arguments` into an array, thus providing you with all of an array's helper functions such as `map`, `forEach`, `filter`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend using ECMAScript 6 [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), which will Bind trailing parameters to an array. With this solution you don't need to touch the `arguments` object and your code will be simplified. The downside of this solution is that it does not work across most browsers, so instead you will have to use a JS compiler such as Babel. Under the hood Babel transforms `arguments` into a Array with a for loop.

```
function sortArgs(...args) {
  return args.sort();
}
```

If you can not use a ECMAScript 6, I recommend looking at some of the other answers such as @Jonathan Fingland

```
function sortArgs() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return args.sort();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), which takes an array-like object (such as `arguments`) as argument and converts it to array:

```js
(function() {
  console.log(Array.from(arguments));
}(1, 2, 3));
```

Note that it doesn't work in some older browsers like IE 11, so if you want to support these browsers, you should use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 4):

Lodash:

```
var args = _.toArray(arguments);
```

in action:

```
(function(){ console.log(_.toArray(arguments).splice(1)); })(1, 2, 3)
```

produces:

```
[2,3]
```

Comment: Why not `_.toArray`?

Comment: But `_.toArray` is more appropriate.

Comment: I would argue _.slice is more appropriate since you often want to drop some leading arguments.

Answer (score 3):

```
function sortArg(){
var args = Array.from(arguments); return args.sort();
}
```

```js
 function sortArg(){
    var args = Array.from(arguments); 
    return args.sort();
    }
 
 console.log(sortArg('a', 'b', 1, 2, '34', 88, 20, '19', 39, 'd', 'z', 'ak', 'bu', 90));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another Answer.

Use Black Magic Spells:

```
function sortArguments() {
  arguments.__proto__ = Array.prototype;
  return arguments.slice().sort();
}
```

Firefox, Chrome, Node.js, IE11 are OK.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution... if you want to make your code completely unreadable. Also, `__proto__` is deprecated. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`Object.setPrototypeOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf)

Explanation: Set `prototype` of `arguments` to `Array.prototype`

```js
function toArray() {
  return Object.setPrototypeOf(arguments, Array.prototype)
} 

console.log(toArray("abc", 123, {def:456}, [0,[7,[14]]]))
```

---

Explanation: Take each index of `arguments` , place item into an array at corresponding index of array.

could alternatively use [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function toArray() {
  return [].map.call(arguments, (_,k,a) => a[k])
} 

console.log(toArray("abc", 123, {def:456}, [0,[7,[14]]]))
```

---

Explanation: Take each index of `arguments` , place item into an array at corresponding index of array.

[`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop

```js
function toArray() {
 let arr = []; for (let prop of arguments) arr.push(prop); return arr
} 

console.log(toArray("abc", 123, {def:456}, [0,[7,[14]]]))
```

---

or [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Explanation: Create object, set properties of object to items at each index of `arguments`; set `prototype` of created object to `Array.prototype`

```js
function toArray() {
  var obj = {};
  for (var prop in arguments) {
    obj[prop] = {
      value: arguments[prop],
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  } 
  return Object.create(Array.prototype, obj);
}

console.log(toArray("abc", 123, {def: 456}, [0, [7, [14]]]))
```

Comment: You've been [asking people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/315961/1906307) whether your answer satisfies the warning under the question about "long answers". It seems to me the main issue with your answer is that you do not explain *why* one should use any of the methods you show here. There's no way I would use any of the solutions you propose because they are all worse than the solutions in the accepted answer. For instance, your reference to the doc of `Object.setPrototypeOf` warns that it is a "very slow operation". Why on earth would I use this over `Array.prototype.slice.call`?

Comment: @Louis Updated Answer with explanations for each approach. Question at OP appear to be _"Is there a built-in way to do it using the standard library?"_ , not _"why one should use any of the methods"_ that are built-in? How could any user that posted an Answer accurately determine if the posted solutions are "right" for OP ? It would seem that it is up to OP to determine this? Actually, this portion of notification is what interested this user: _"explain why your answer is right"_ . Do any of the Answers provided to this Question state: "This answer is "right" because: x,y,z"?

Comment: What I've explained is how SO generally works. Whether or not the OP wants to know why one solution is better than the other is totally irrelevant, because the questions posted for SO are not *primarily* for the OP but for the hundreds and thousand of people who will read the question and its answers later. Also, the people who vote on answers are not required to vote according to whatever the OP might be satisfied with.

Answer (score 0):

Benshmarck 3 methods :

```
function test()
{
  console.log(arguments.length + ' Argument(s)');

  var i = 0;
  var loop = 1000000;
  var t = Date.now();
  while(i < loop)
  {
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0); 
      i++;
  }
  console.log(Date.now() - t);


  i = 0,
  t = Date.now();
  while(i < loop)
  {
      Array.apply(null, arguments);
      i++;
  }
  console.log(Date.now() - t);

  i = 0,
  t = Date.now();
  while(i < loop)
  {
      arguments.length == 1 ? [arguments[0]] : Array.apply(null, arguments);
      i++;
  }
  console.log(Date.now() - t);
}

test();
test(42);
test(42, 44);
test(42, 44, 88, 64, 10, 64, 700, 15615156, 4654, 9);
test(42, 'truc', 44, '47', 454, 88, 64, '@ehuehe', 10, 64, 700, 15615156, 4654, 9,97,4,94,56,8,456,156,1,456,867,5,152489,74,5,48479,89,897,894,894,8989,489,489,4,489,488989,498498);
```

RESULT?

```
0 Argument(s)
256
329
332
1 Argument(s)
307
418
4
2 Argument(s)
375
364
367
10 Argument(s)
962
601
604
40 Argument(s)
3095
1264
1260
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Would like to suggest to modified to something like `arguments.length == 1?[arguments[0]]:Array.apply(null, arguments);` to prevent the function is called with only one integer argument `dummyFn(3)` and causes result `[,,]`

Comment: @nevermind good job, I edit, your version is better ;) But I dont understand `dummyFn(3)` what is this? this function not exist...

Comment: Uh... never mind, just a example want to show how a function called with only one integer argument and causes a fixed size empty array, sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sortArgs(...args) {
  return args.sort(function (a, b) { return a - b; });
}

document.body.innerHTML = sortArgs(1, 2, 3, 4).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Although rest parameters work well, if you want to continue to use `arguments` for some reason, consider

```
function sortArgs() {
  return [...arguments].sort()
}
```

`[...arguments]` can be considered a sort of alternative to `Array.from(arguments)`, which also works perfectly well.

An ES7 alternative is an array comprehension:

```
[for (i of arguments) i].sort()
```

This could be easiest if you want to process or filter the arguments prior to sorting:

```
[for (i of arguments) if (i % 2) Math.log(i)].sort()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function x(){
   var rest = [...arguments]; console.log(rest);return     
   rest.constructor;
 };
 x(1,2,3)
```

I tried simple destructing technique

Answer (score 0):

The Arguments object is only available inside a function body. Although you can index the Arguments Object like an array, it is not an array. It does not have any array properties other than length.

```js
// function arguments length 5
function properties(a,b,c,d,e){
var function_name= arguments.callee.name
var arguments_length= arguments.length;
var properties_length=  properties.length; 
var function_from= properties.caller.name;
console.log('I am the function name: '+ function_name);
console.log('I am the function length, I am function spacific: '+ properties_length); 
console.log('I am the arguments length, I am context/excution spacific: '+ arguments_length);
console.log('I am being called From: '+  function_from );
}

// arguments 3
function parent(){
properties(1,2,3);
}

//arguments length 3 because execution spacific
parent();
```

Although it can be indexed like an array as you can see in this example:

```js
function add(){

var sum=0;

for(var i=0; i< arguments.length;i++){

sum = sum + arguments[i];

}

return sum;

}

console.log(add(1,2,3));
```

However, the Arguments object is not an array and does not have any other properties other than length.

You can convert the arguments object into an array at which point you can access the Arguments object.

There are many ways you can access the arguments object inside a function body, and these include:

1. you can call the Array.prototoype.slice.call method.

Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)

```js
function giveMeArgs(arg1,arg2){

var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
return args
}

console.log( giveMeArgs(1,2));
```

2. you can use the array literal

[].slice.call(arguments).

```js
function giveMeArgs(arg1,arg2){

var args = [].slice.call(arguments);

return args;

}

console.log( giveMeArgs(1,2) );
```

3. you can use Rest ...

```js
function giveMeArgs(...args){

return args;

}

console.log(giveMeArgs(1,2))
```

4. you can use spread [...]

```js
function giveMeArgs(){

var args = [...arguments];
return args;

}

console.log(giveMeArgs(1,2));
```

5. you can use Array.from()

```js
function giveMeArgs(){

var args = Array.from(arguments);

return args;

}

console.log(giveMeArgs(1,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable function to do it with any arguments, the simplest one is something like this:

```
function sortArgs() {
  return [...arguments].sort();
}

sortArgs('ali', 'reza', 1, 2, 'a'); //[1, 2, "a", "ali", "reza"];
```

Spread syntax can be used in **ES6** and above...

But if you'd like to use something compatible with **ES5** and below, you can use `Array.prototype.slice.call`, so you code looks like this:

```
function sortArgs() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).sort();
}

sortArgs('ali', 'reza', 1, 2, 'a'); //[1, 2, "a", "ali", "reza"];
```

There are also few other ways to do this, for Example using `Array.from` or loop through the **arguments** and assign them to a new array...

Answer (score -2):

This is a very old question, but I think I have a solution that is slightly easier to type than previous solutions and doesn't rely on external libraries:

```
function sortArguments() {
  return Array.apply(null, arguments).sort();
}
```

Comment: `Array.apply` won't work if you have only a single positive integer argument. It is because `new Array(3)` creates an array length of `3`. To be more specific the result will be `[undefined, undefined, undefined]` and not `[3]`.