# Call function with array of arguments

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

Can I call a function with array of arguments in a convenient way in JavaScript?

Example:

```
var fn = function() {
    console.log(arguments);
}

var args = [1,2,3];

fn(args);
```

I need `arguments` to be `[1,2,3]`, just like my array.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Since the introduction of ES6, you can use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) in function calls:

```js
const args = [1, 2, 3];

fn(...args);

function fn() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

Before ES6, you needed to use [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Objects:Function:apply).

```js
var args = [1, 2, 3];
fn.apply(null, args);

function fn() {
  console.log(arguments);
}
```

Both will produce the equivalent function call:

```
fn(1, 2, 3);
```

Notice that I used `null` as the first argument of the `apply` example, which will set the `this` keyword to the global object (`window`) inside `fn` or `undefined` under strict mode.

Also, you should know that the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object is not an array, it's an array-like object, that contains numeric indexes corresponding to the arguments that were used to call your function, a `length` property that gives you the number of arguments used.

In ES6, if you want to access a variable number of arguments as an array, you can also use the [rest syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) in the function parameter list:

```js
function fn(...args) {
  args.forEach(arg => console.log(arg))
}

fn(1, 2, 3)
```

Before ES6, if you wanted to make an array from your `arguments` object, you commonly used the `Array.prototype.slice` method.

```js
function fn() {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
  console.log(args);
}

fn(1, 2, 3);
```

**Edit:** In response to your comment, yes, you could use the `shift` method and set its returned value as the context (the `this` keyword) on your function:

```
fn.apply(args.shift(), args);
```

But remember that `shift` will remove the first element from the original array, and your function will be called without that first argument.

If you still need to call your function with all your other arguments, you can:

```
fn.apply(args[0], args);
```

And if you don't want to change the context, you could extract the first argument inside your function:

```js
function fn(firstArg, ...args) {
  console.log(args, firstArg);
}

fn(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

In ES5, that would be a little more verbose.

```js
function fn() {
  const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        firstArg = args.shift();

  console.log(args, firstArg);
}

fn(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: What if I want the scope to be the first element of the Array? do I need to fake it using shift() ?

Comment: @David: What do you mean by scope? The `this` keyword ?

Comment: Yes, using apply(), the first argument becomes the scope(this) for the function, right? The scope in this case need to be the first array element.

Comment: "fn.apply(args.shift(), args);" -- Does javascript guarantee a left-to-right function argument evaluation order?  Is args passed by reference?  Expressions of form "f(modify(object), object))" trigger my spider senses...

Comment: @CMS This question is only about calling a function with array of arguments. I think that talking about `arguments` not being a real array is little off-topic here (it would help OP, but not future visitors). Adding a link to [How can I convert the “arguments” object to an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript) would be enough.

Answer (score 13):

In ECMAScript 6, you can use [spread syntax (`...`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for that purpose. It's way simpler and easier to understand than [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply).

Code example:

```
const fn = function() {
  console.log(arguments);
}

const args = [1,2,3];

fn(...args);
```