# Javascript: Call function, pass array of arguments, similar to setTimout()'s functionality

Tags: javascript

I want to do what setTimout does, manually, with no timeout.

```
setTimeout(function,0,args);
```

Just call a function and pass it an array of arguments, without knowing or caring how many arguments were there.

Basically I want to proxy the function call through another function.

I'm bad with terminology, sorry.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881905/call-function-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: @Michał Perłakowski not sure how this is a duplicate (already answered) by the link you added since it was asked and answered first? Maybe you're just saying "cleared question here" ?

Comment: @somedev The other question has better answers, see [Should I flag a question as duplicate if it has received better answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251938/3853934)

Comment: @MichałPerłakowski I figured, was just curious

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
function f(a, b, c) { return a + b + c; }
alert(f.apply(f, ['hello', ' ', 'world']));
```

Answer (score 7):

In ES6:

```
function myFunc(a, b, c){
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

var args = [1, 2, 3];
myFunc(...args);
```

Comment: thanks for this!  I <3 ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a function with variable arguments as an argument.  The best way to do this is either an explicit Array or object in general.

```
myFunction(callbackFunction, count, arrayOfOptions);

myFunction(callbackFunction, count, objectOfOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at javascript's [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/arguments) variable. This is an array of all arguments passed in to the function.

So you can create your core function like this:

```
f = function () {
    for (arg in arguments) {
         // do stuff
    }
}
```

Then, create a new function with the right arguments:

```
f2 = function () {
    return f(arg1, arg2, arg3 /* etc. */);
}
```

And pass this function to setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(f2, 0);
```