# Passing Variable length array to function Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

Is there a way to call an addon function with a variable length. I take the user input into a variable that looks like

```
Uinput = [5,3,2];
```

Now i want to call my addon based on these numbers so it would be

```
addon.myaddon(5,3,2);
```

I also want to extend this to n inputs so if my variable of user inputs becomes

```
Uinput = [5,3,2,6,...,n];
```

then the addon will be called like

```
addon.myaddon(5,3,2,6,...,n);

addon.myaddon(Uinput) // will not seperate the inputs by commas are they are in the array variable, it treats the whole array as the input
```

This seems simple enough but it is giving me a bit of trouble. Any tips ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Call function with multiple arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881905/call-function-with-multiple-arguments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
Uinput = [5,3,2,...,7]; // the last number in the array is in position 'n'
addon.myaddon.apply(null, Uinput);
```

This is equivalent to calling:

```
addon.myaddon(Uinput[0], Uinput[1], Uinput[2], ... , Uinput[n]);
```

Real example using [`Math.max`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max):

```
// Basic example
Math.max(1,6,3,8,4,7,3); // returns 8

// Example with any amount of arguments in an array
var mySet = [1,6,3,8,4,7,3];
Math.max.apply(null, mySet); // returns 8
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! i will accept as soon as i can. I knew i was missing something simple