# Calling a variadic function inside a variadic function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, variadic

I have two function a() and b(), both are variadic functions, let say when I call function a() like this :

```
a(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, ...., argn);
```

then the function b() will be called as well inside a(), but without the first argument "arg0" in the arguments list of a() :

```
b(arg1, arg2, arg3, ...., argn);
```

Is there any way for it?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/converting-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Every JavaScript `function` is really just another "object" (object in the JavaScript sense), and comes with an `apply` method (see [Mozilla's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/apply)). You can thus do something like this....

```
b = function(some, parameter, list) { ... }

a = function(some, longer, parameter, list)
{
   // ... Do some work...

   // Convert the arguments object into an array, throwing away the first element
   var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);

   // Call b with the remaining arguments and current "this"
   b.apply(this, args);
}
```

Comment: Cool, I have just done a quick test and it works fine. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you need to use the prototype explicitly? Can't you arguments.slice(1) or something?