# Prepend argument to arguments then apply

Tags: javascript, arguments, call, apply

I have a function, `message` that takes one param to define the type of message and then it joins any other arguments to form the message, purely a nicety.

It looks like this:

```
function message(type) {
    var msg = _.rest(arguments).join(" ");

    // Really the type will be used to set the class on a div
    // But I'm just using console.log to keep it simple for now.
    console.log(type + ": " + msg);
}
```

I want to provide helper functions, `error`, `warning`, `info`, which simply call `message` with the right type. I'm just unsure on the best way to go about this. I cant think of two ways but I'm not sure if I'm going about it correctly or that perhaps I'm overcomplicating things.

The first way seems a bit redundant, make a new array containing the first arg and the arguments then flatten it.

```
message.apply(this, _.flatten(["error", arguments]));
```

The second way feels a bit... messy?

```
Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, "error");
message.apply(this, arguments);
```

Though from my experiement:

```
(function() {
    Array.prototype.unshift.call(arguments, 0);
    console,log(arguments);
})(1, 2, 3);
```

I get the following output:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, undefined, undefined, undefined, ..., undefined]
```

Answer (score 9):

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // Make real array from arguments
args.unshift("error");
message.apply(this, args);
```

See [How can I convert the "arguments" object to an array in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/converting-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript/960870#960870)

Comment: Should use .call to make it work everywhere
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

Answer (score 5):

In ES5 this might be slightly more efficient than converting to a real array first and then `unshift`:

```
var args = Array.prototype.concat.apply(["error"], arguments);
message.apply(this, args);
```

EDIT: Better to avoid flattening input arrays:

```
var args = ["error"];
args.push.apply(args, arguments);
message.apply(this, args);
```

Comment: Be careful using this, as if elements of `arguments` are arrays they will be 'flattened' into the array instead of being added as an element themselves. e.g. `var args = Array.prototype.concat.apply(["error"], ["apple", "banana", ["carrot", "cherry"]])` incorrectly becomes `args =
 ["error", "apple", "banana", "carrot", "cherry"]`.