# How to get array of values of attributes from objectarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

i have a problem with the following situation:

I have an Array of Objects which all contains the same attribute, which is called `src`

Before adding a new Object (with an `src` attribute too), I want to check if the value already exists in just one `src` attribute in the Objects Array.

Therefore I wanted to use `$.inArray()` with the new `src` as first parameter and as array not the array of objects, but the array of the values of the attributes from the objects array.

As Example:

I have

```
var arrayOfObjects = [{
    src : "source1",
    otherAttribute : "value"
}, {
    src : "source2",
    otherAttribute : "value"
}];
```

My question is: Is there a build in function in JavaScript/jQuery which returns

```
["source1","source2"]
```

when called with `functionX(arrayOfObjects)` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert the "arguments" object to an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can always use [**Array.prototype.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var sources = arrayOfObjects.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.src;
});
```

... but for your specific case, I'd rather choose a bit different approach - checking against array directly with [**Array.prototype.some()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```
function doesSourceExist(source) {
  return arrayOfObjects.some(function(obj) { 
    return obj.src === source; 
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much! Because I need the index of the element anyway (to focus this element) I used `$.inArray` now :)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer but an addendum to @raina77ow's answer for cleaner code.

```
function property(prop) {
  return function(obj) {
    return obj[prop];
  };
}

var sources = arrayOfObjects.map(property('src'));
```