# jQuery How to retrieve .trigger() extra parameters when triggering a custom function

Tags: jquery

I have built a jQuery custom function

```
jQuery.fn.myfunction = function(){ ... }
```

This custom function is called using .trigger()

```
my_element.trigger('change', [ "Custom", "Event" ]);
```

I am trying to retrieve the array `[ "Custom", "Event" ]`  in the custom function `myfunction` but I can't find how to do so.

Any help? many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter is the event object. All following parameters are custom.

```
jQuery.fn.myfunction = function(e,customParm1,customParm2){ ... }
```

See the [`.trigger()`](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) documentation:

> ```
> $( "#foo" ).on( "custom", function( event, param1, param2 ) {
>   alert( param1 + "\n" + param2 );
> });
> $( "#foo").trigger( "custom", [ "Custom", "Event" ] );
> ```

If you really need an *array* of all custom args, then you can just use:

```
var customArgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // convert arguments to array
customArgs.shift(); // get rid of event arg
console.log( customArgs ); // outputs [ "Custom", "Event" ]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rq3hj03x/

Comment: Kudos to [How can I convert the “arguments” object to an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript)