# MongoDB - Shell Scripting - $in arguments not working

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am using `db.system.js.save` to save js functions on the server.

I wrote this script so far

```
function () {
cursor = db.MyCollection.find({_id: {$in:[arguments]}})
                                             ^ this does not work
        while(cursor.hasNext()){print(cursor.next())};       
}
```

I am calling it with the following argument `findAllDocuments(ObjectId("544a30c80c80d5809180b"),<more objects>);`, but it is not working.

Do I have to call it `arguments` differently? Because `arguments[0]` is working for example.

---

Edit: For clarification `arguments` are the parameters of the javascript function.

`findAllDocuments(ObjectId("544a30c80c80d5809180b"),ObjectId("544a30c80c80d5809180b"), <and more objectIds>);`
If I use it like this it does work, but the arguments length can be variable.

```
function () {
cursor = db.MyCollection.find({_id: {$in:[arguments[0],arguments[1]}})
                                             ^ this does work
        while(cursor.hasNext()){print(cursor.next())};       
}
```

---

EDIT 2:

How can I use the $in correctly in $ref?

```
 cursor = db.MyCollection.find({"trainer" : {
        "$ref" : "Contact",
        "$id" : {$in : [ObjectId("556d901118bfd4901e2a3833")]}
                  ^it executes successfully, but does not find anything
    }})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `arguments` is already an array you don't need to pass it inside another array:

```
var arguments = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
db.col.find({_id: {$in: arguments}})
```

If the objects you are working with are *not* arrays you have to wrap them within an array:

```
db.col.find({_id: {$in: [arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]]}})
```

Keep in mind that your `$in` operator won't be able to work with nested arrays so if each element of your array is an array itself you might need to merge them together into one larger array.

Comment: I removed the brackets and went with this `{_id: {$in:arguments}}`, but I am getting the error _"$err" : "Can't canonicalize query: BadValue $in needs an array",_

Comment: @MuratK. - so from this we can deduce  that `arguments` is not in fact an array. Can you add to your post the value of that variable?

Comment: I updated it. The arguments are the parameters of the javascript function.

Comment: @MuratK. - so you are saying that the `arguments` variable has this sort of value: `[ ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...), ObjectId(...), ...]`? Is that the variable that you are working with?

Comment: Yes it was, apparently arguments Object is not a _real_ array. [I had to use this to make it a array var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript). It is now working. Thanks

Comment: @MuratK. - ohhhhh I see what you mean now. `arguments` was the [actual `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) and not just a variable called arguments :) So yes, you are correct. It looks and behaves like an array but it's not actually a "real" array. [The docs call it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) `"an Array-like object"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79424/discussion-between-murat-k-and-lix).

Comment: One quick question, could you look at my Edit2 pls?

Comment: @MuratK. - you might want to open a new post for a separate question. Sorry, but I can't chat ATM.