# arguments vs Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments

What is the difference between using arguments and Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0) in a function?
I don't see there is any much difference between both, so How would I know when I am supposed to use which one?

```js
function arr(){
  return arguments; // or return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);
}
arr([1,2,3],[4,5,6]);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I convert the "arguments" object to an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript).  The first paragraph explain several disadvantages of the `arguments`object and why a programmer would convert it to an actual `Array`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `arguments` is an *"array-like"* object, not an array.

You can convert the `arguments` object to a real array by slicing it, like so

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
```

This gives you an array, with array properties like `forEach`, `pop` etc. which objects like `arguments` don't have (except length, which `arguments` do have).

It is generally (almost) never a good idea to slice the `arguments` object, [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) gives the warning

> You should not slice on arguments because it prevents optimizations in
>   JavaScript engines (V8 for example). Instead, try constructing a new
>   array by iterating through the arguments object.

Also there should be no real need to pass arguments to a function, only to return them.

Comment: To be specific, it's an array-like object. Which is generally what people call non-arrays that are indexed by numbers and have a `.length` property. There are many such things in js. The `HTMLCollection` returned by `document.getElementsByClassName()` is another example

Comment: @slebetman - It's really just an obect with a `length` property, often called "array-like".

Answer (score 1):

The arguments object is not a real array. It is a special type of object and does not have any Array properties except "length".

To make an array from the arguments object, use Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

Answer (score 0):

`arguments` variable is special kind of `Object`, and is not `Array`. So, you can't use `.forEach`, `.map`, '.push' and other array functions with it.

You have to convert `arguments` to `Array` and then you can work with value as array

```js
function test(){
  console.log(arguments.forEach); // undefined
  var argsArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0);
  console.log(argsArray.forEach); // function
}
test();
```