# How to filter an array and compare it with the function arguments in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have tried the below code, but I am not getting satisfactory results.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
// Remove all the values

var newArray = arr.filter(function(x){

if(x == arr[0]){
 return x;
}
});
return newArray;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Please indent/format your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest one:

```
function without(array, exclude) {
    return array.filter(function(x) { return exclude.indexOf(x) === -1; });
}
```

You could use it like this: `without([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2]) // returns [3,4,5]`

Or you could try dealing with arguments list like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript), but the idea would be the same.

Comment: Or you could use `includes`, which would also find `NaN` :-)