# JavaScript arguments object MDN guide

Tags: javascript, arguments

Could anyone give a detailed explanation of what each term in this line of code actually does? I know this is to convert the arguments object into a real Array but I don't understand how it does.

```
   var args = (arguments.length === 1?[arguments[0]]:Array.apply(null, arguments));
```

Comment: Wherever you found that code, throw it away. As far as possible. And use an idiomatic [standard approach](http://stackoverflow.com/q/960866/1048572) instead.

Comment: Which of the terms exactly are unclear?

Comment: Why??? That's a harsh reaction to the code. I don't understand the following part: arguments.length === 1?[arguments[0]]:

Comment: If the `arguments` object has a length of `1` (exactly one argument), then it creates an array literal with that argument as the only element, else ….

Answer (score -1):

```
function someFunc() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return args;
}
someFunc(1,2,3);  //[1, 2, 3]
```

The `arguments` object is an array-like object (not an array) local to every function and contains an entry for each argument passed into the function.

In the above, we use `Array.prototype` to create an instance of an array.  It could also be written this way `var args = [].slice.call(arguments);`.

Then we use the `slice()` method.  Slice can be used for array-like objects (in this case our `arguments` object) as long as you bind the method to the object.  For binding in this case, we use `call()`.  You could also use other binding functions such as `apply()`.

The `call()` method takes in the `arguments` object, which is the `this` value provided for `slice()`.

It's worth noting that in EcmaScript 2015 this can be done in a simpler way using [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) and the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).  The following is the ES2015 equivalent:

```
function someFunc(...args) {
    return args;
}
someFunc(1,2,3);  //[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: While everything you said is correct, and demonstrates the proper way to do this, your post does not answer the question.

Comment: I started putting together my answer before the OP edit, which added the code example.  Because I didn't have that context, I demonstrated a simple example on how to create an array from an arguments object.

Comment: Thank you Maverick976 for the answer and explanation, but as already stated the code came later, my excuses, and the answer is different.