# Convert Array-like objects, Array.prototype.slice or Array.from

Tags: javascript

I know there are two ways to convert Array-like objects to Array.

1. `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`
2. `Array.from(arguments)`

I wonder what's the differences between them , which one should I use to convert Array-like objects.

Comment: As far as [__Browser compatibility__](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility) is concerned, go with the `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`([`Polyfill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill) is available though...)

Comment: Or `[...arguments]`.

Comment: But be careful in old IE 8 and lower. If host objects are passed as *this* to built–in methods (e.g. passing an HTML collection as *this* to *slice*) you will get an error. However, if you have a polyfill for [*from*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill), that will not be an issue.

Comment: `Array.prototype.slice.call` is very different from `Array.from`. It's the fastest and most compatible way to create an array from an existing array-like. It works on all browsers including all IE except IE8- when used on host objects such as a NodeList. However ES6's `Array.from` is much slower because it starts with an array of length 0 which requires log n memory allocations, unlike `Array.prototype.slice.call`. And it differs because it fills all the gaps with `undefined` and also creates arrays from iterables. So if you're working with an array-like, use `[].slice.call`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`Array.prototype.slice.call` has been the long-standing mechanism for converting array-like objects to arrays. If you are looking for browser compatibility use this (although it appears that on some older browsers like IE8 and below this will not work at all).

`Array.from` was introduced ECMA6 in June of 2015. It accomplishes the same thing as the prior mechanism, only in a more fluent and concise manner. In addition `Array.from` can convert more structures into arrays such as generators.

Learn about [array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Comment: Actually `Array.from` accomplishes **more**, since it can turn generators into arrays etc.

Comment: For the record, [*ECMA-262*](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) is the name of the standard (all versions). *ECMAScript* is the name of the language. [*Edition 6*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) is the current version of ECMA-262, its short name is *ECMAScript 2015*.

Answer (score 3):

`Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)` works faster in many browser than `Array.from(arguments)`.

You can look at the [results](https://jsperf.com/array-from-vs-array-prototype-slice) here.

Comment: It's remarkable how much faster it is, too.  And it's only getting faster in newer version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be portable, use the first method.  The second method is part of ECMAscript 6 and is therefore not well supported across a range of browsers.

Answer (score 0):

slice works on anything that has a length property, which arguments conveniently does.

Array.from simply convert Array-like or Iterable objects into Array instances.

Unfortunately, Array.from and Rest Parameters are currently only implemented in newer versions of Firefox and Google Chrome

Please refer to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Array-like objects are objects that have indexed elements. and a length property, similar to arrays, but they may not have all the methods of arrays like push(), pop() & others.

Array destructuring is introduced in ECMAScript (ES6).

```
 // Example array-like object

const arrayLike = {
  0: 'a',
  1: 'b',
  2: 'c',
  length: 3,
  [Symbol.iterator]: function () {
    let index = 0;
    return {
      next: () => ({
        value: this[index++],
        done: index > this.length
      })
    };
  }
};

// Now it's iterable
const array1 = Array.from(arrayLike);
console.log(array1);  // output: ['a', 'b', 'c']

const array2 = [...arrayLike];
console.log(array2);  // output: ['a', 'b', 'c']

const array3 = Array.prototype.slice.call(arrayLike);
console.log(array3);  // output: ['a', 'b', 'c']
```