# How to convert to array in Java script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, ajax

I have the following loop to send data to ajax function as json :

```
foreach($careers->getItems() as $item){


                            if($item->getDepartment()==$departmentID && $item->getLocation()==$locationID) {

                                $arr = array('department' => $item->getDepartment(), 'careerLocation' => $item->getLocation(),
                                'title' => $item->getTitle(), 'job' => $item->getJob(), 'logo' => $item->getLogo());

                            echo json_encode($arr);

                            }       

                            }
```

The Result is:

```
 {"department":"2","careerLocation":"1","title":"fd","job":"sa","logo":"sa"}  
{"department":"2","careerLocation":"1","title":"sa","job":"sa","logo":"sa"}
```

what should I do to type json correctly?

Comment: That's not valid JSON. It needs to be either one object or an array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert the "arguments" object to an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

That is not valid JSON.

```json
{  
  "department":"2",
  "careerLocation":"1",
  "title":"fd",
  "job":"sa",
  "logo":"sa"
}{  
  "department":"2",
  "careerLocation":"1",
  "title":"sa",
  "job":"sa",
  "logo":"sa"
}
```

The two `}{` appearing next to each other like that is not allowed, as any decent JSON linter should have warned you:

[image: syntax error]

Comment: Still not valid JSON. It's missing the comma.

Comment: @Vld oh wow I didn't notice that the OP had just mashed two Objects together... wtf?

Comment: ` foreach($careers->getItems() as $item){
            
          
       if($item->getDepartment()==$departmentID && $item->getLocation()==$locationID) {
     
        $arr = array('department' => $item->getDepartment(), 'careerLocation' => $item->getLocation(),
        'title' => $item->getTitle(), 'job' => $item->getJob(), 'logo' => $item->getLogo());
        
       echo json_encode($arr);
        
                            }    
   
                      }` i used this foreach to print json to ajax data, is it correct ?