# JS arguments.forEach is not a function

Tags: javascript, foreach

So this code works perfectly

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4];
arr.forEach(function (el) {
    console.log(el);
})
```

But if i try to do this:

```
function printArgsInfo() {
    arguments.forEach(function (el) {
        console.log(el);
    });
}
printArgsInfo(2, 3, 2.5, -110.5564, false);
```

arguments`.forEach` is not a function

Even though `arguments` is an array and if Itry to do this with a `for in` loop it still works.

Comment: Don't use `arguments`. It's pretty much obsolete.

Comment: Replace `arguments.forEach...` with `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).forEach...`

Answer (score 18):

[`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is an array-like object, but not an array:

```js
var doThing = function() {
    console.log(arguments.constructor.name)
    console.log([].constructor.name)
}

doThing("someArgument")
```

Will return `Object` for `arguments` and `Array` for the empty array `[]`.

### ES6 and newer

With ES6, you could use [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), as *torazaburo* suggests.

> The **rest parameter** syntax allows us to represent an indefinite number of arguments as an array.

```js
function printArgsInfo(...args) {
    args.forEach(el => console.log(el));
}

printArgsInfo(2, 3, 2.5, -110.5564, false);
```

### ES5 and older

For ES5 and older, you could borrow the method from [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) it with `argument` as `thisArg`.

```js
function printArgsInfo() {
    [].forEach.call(arguments, function (el) {
        console.log(el);
    });
}

printArgsInfo(2, 3, 2.5, -110.5564, false);
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't suggest the obvious `[...arguments].forEach`. Or more preferably, just say `function printArgsInfo(...args)`.

Comment: @torazaburo, right, added that as well, thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 7):

Per the MDN Docs:

> The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the arguments passed to a function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

So, it is not a true array and does not share the Array object's prototype -- which is where the `forEach` method is defined.

Interestingly, also from the MDN docs:

> You can also use the Array.from() method or the spread operator to convert arguments to a real Array

```
var args = Array.from(arguments);
```

So, here is a working example with your code:

```
function printArgsInfo() {
    var args = Array.from(arguments);

    args.forEach(function (el) {
        console.log(el);
    });
}

printArgsInfo(2, 3, 2.5, -110.5564, false);
```

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/arguments-array  ye, but explains it somewhat beter

Answer (score 4):

> Even though arguments is an array

It isn't.

```js
function myFunc() {
    console.log(arguments instanceof Array);
}

myFunc(1,2,3);
```

The [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) is an array-like object. It isn't an array.

Comment: Also maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/960866/how-can-i-convert-the-arguments-object-to-an-array-in-javascript

Comment: console.log(typeof arguments); yes low it says its an object and it seems logical not to be albe to foreach it, never tought that it wasn't an array

Comment: `console.log(typeof [])` — arrays are objects (but not all objects are arrays).