# Converting array entries into an object with a variable number of parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5

I currently have a bit of code that is as follows:

```js
      $.when(aiFileGen, foeFileGen, foe2FileGen, playerFileGen).then(function (
        aiFiles,
        foeFiles,
        foe2Files,
        playerFiles
      ) {
        var files = _.assign({}, aiFiles, foeFiles, foe2Files, playerFiles);
        self.files(files);
        done.resolve();
      });
```

A snapshot `self.files()` is as follows:

```
Object {/pa/ai/unit_maps/ai_unit_map.json.ai: Object, /pa/units/sea/hover_ship/hover_ship.json.ai: Object, /pa/units/sea/fabrication_barge/fabrication_barge.json.ai: Object, /pa/units/sea/drone_carrier/drone/drone.json.ai: Object, /pa/units/sea/drone_carrier/carrier/carrier.json.ai: Object…}
```

The problem with this method is that it assumes a set number of parameters, but the number of parameters can change. Therefore I have tried to convert to something more dynamic.

```js
      var filesToProcess = [aiFileGen, playerFileGen];

      filesToProcess.push(foeFileGen, foe2FileGen);

      $.when.apply($, filesToProcess).always(function () {
        self.files(_.assign({}, arguments));
        done.resolve();
      });
```

However, the output of `self.files()` is as follows:

```
Object {0: Object, 1: Object, 2: Object, 3: Object}
```

Where have I gone wrong in my conversion of method 1 to method 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you always call `_.assign({}, arguments)` with 2 arguments. Instead you want to pass each argument in `arguments` as separate argument to `_.assign`.

This can be done similar to how you've also changed the `$.when` call. However you'll have to [convert the `arguments` to an array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/960866/3982562) first so you can add the additional `{}` argument.

```
var assignArgs = Array.prototype.push.apply([{}], arguments);
self.files(_.assign.apply(_, assignArgs);
```

However I'd recommend taking a look at the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [rest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) syntax (`...`). This makes passing and accepting a variable amount of parameters a lot easier.

```
$.when.apply($, filesToProcess).always(function () {
  var assignArgs = Array.prototype.push.apply([{}], arguments);
  self.files(_.assign.apply(_, assignArgs);
  done.resolve();
});

// can be changed to

$.when(...filesToProcess).always(function () {
  self.files(_.assign({}, ...arguments));
  done.resolve();
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm working with Chromium 28, so can't use spread and rest. However, your answer worked like a charm, thanks. One correction I made is to add some missing brackets `self.files(_.assign.apply(_, ({}, arguments)));`, else it comes back as undefined.

Comment: @Quitch That is a mistake on my part. [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) only accepts 2 arguments, the `this` argument and and argument list. Your proposed solution doesn't have the effect you think it has (you are using the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator)). It is the same as calling `_.assign.apply(_, arguments)`. This means you are mutating the first argument passed. This might not be an issue depending on your scenario.

Comment: It appeared to work fine in my testing, however, I will look at switching to the edited answer to be safe, thanks.

Comment: I ended up using `self.files(_.assign.apply(_, arguments);` as that appears to work correctly. The new method was generating an error about argument type.